# What is causing "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python

This code produces the error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
amount = float(input("Enter the purchase price please."))
down_payment=amount *0.10
monthly_rate = (amount - down_payment) *.05

ending_balance=amount-down_payment

print("|Ø-6s|Ø-16s|Ø-9s|Ø-8s|Ø-14s|" % ("Month" , "Current Balance" , "Interest" , "Payment" , "Ending Balance"))
month = 1
while True:
    starting_balance = ending_balance
    interest = starting_balance * 0.01
    final_amount = (starting_balance+interest)

    if monthly_rate > final_amount:
          monthly_rate = final_amount


    ending_balance = final_amount - monthly_rate

    print("|Ø-6f|Ø-16f|Ø-9f|Ø-8f|Ø-14f|" % (month , starting_balance , interest , monthly_rate , ending_balance))
    month+=1

    if ending_balance <= 0:
      break
```

Error:

```
<module>
  print("|Ø-6s|Ø-16s|Ø-9s|Ø-8s|Ø-14s|" % ("Month" , "Current Balance" , "Interest" , "Payment" , "Ending Balance"))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: You don't provide formatting instructions for any of your values, so none of the values are used, leaving them all left over.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `%` instead of `Ø` in your formating strings.

```
print("|%-6s|%-16s|%-9s|%-8s|%-14s|" % ("Month" , "Current Balance" , "Interest" , "Payment" , "Ending Balance"))
```

and

```
print("|%-6f|%-16f|%-9f|%-8f|%-14f|" % (month , starting_balance , interest , monthly_rate , ending_balance))
```

And see: https://pyformat.info/